# How does enum#with_object differ from enum#each_with_object?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

The documentation says:

> [`enum#each_with_object
>   :-`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Enumerator/each_with_object)
>
> *Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object, obj, and returns obj*

> [`enum#with_object:-`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Enumerator/with_object)
>
> *Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object, obj, and returns obj*

But when I tried the below on the both constructs, one gave me the output as expected but the others didn't. So I suspect there is a difference between those two constructs.

#### Using `each_with_object`

```
%w(foo bar).each_with_object({}) { |str, hsh| hsh[str] = str.upcase }
=> {"foo"=>"FOO", "bar"=>"BAR"}
```

*success here!*

#### Using `with_object`

```
%w(foo bar).with_object({}) { |str, hsh| hsh[str] = str.upcase }
 => NoMethodError: undefined method `with_object' for ["foo", "bar"]:Array
    from (irb):1
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

*failed here!*

So what is the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`each` returns an Enumerator object.

```
%w(foo bar).each.class
=> Enumerator
```

So, for the first case, the array'll be converted to `Enumerator` first, then works on the `with_object`.

If you want the second case works, you have to convert the array to Enumerator. You can use `.to_enum`, `.each`, or `.map` to convert the array.

```
%w(foo bar).map.with_object({}) { |str, hsh| hsh[str] = str.upcase }
=> {"foo"=>"FOO", "bar"=>"BAR"}
```

More details: [Enumerator](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator)

Comment: @DoLoveSky Not really: `each.with_object` & `each_with_object` are the same number of characters (the former being one less key stroke if you count the shift key).

Comment: @DoLoveSky No, I don’t, because it doesn’t save keystrokes at all.

Answer (score 6):

`with object` only works on enumerators, which means that you have to chain it on to something that returns one. eg.

```
%w(foo bar).each.with_object({}) { |str, h| h[str] = str.upcase }

%w(foo bar).detect.with_object(obj) { ... }
```

So, you can call `with_object` on anything that returns an enumerator if you don't give it a block (such as `map`, `reduce`, `detect`, `find_all`...). This includes anything that mixes in [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html).

`each_with_object` is essentially an alias for `each.with_object`.

Comment: Could you just elaborate the `%w(foo bar).detect.with_object(obj) { ... }` construct?

Comment: Added. It's just an example of something else that returns an enumerator, that isn't `each`.