# How to count non-unique values in a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get a count of all the items `[:item_id]` with more than 1 occurance. This is what I have written – it's wrong I know. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

```
subscriptions = [
  {user_id: 1, item_id: 3},
  {user_id: 3, item_id: 2},
  {user_id: 2, item_id: 3},
  {user_id: 6, item_id: 5},
  {user_id: 6, item_id: 2},
  {user_id: 1, item_id: 4}
]

unique_id = subscriptions_list.map {|id| id[:item_id]} > 1 }    
puts unique_id.count
```

Comment: I would try `reduce` instead of map and use a Hash as Accumulator, ids as key and integers as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
subscriptions.each.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |subscription, counts| 
    counts[subscription[:item_id]] += 1
end
# => {3=>2, 2=>2, 5=>1, 4=>1}
```

- `each` will iterate over each element of `subscription`,
- `with_object` is used to give an arbitrary object during an iteration, and return it,
- `Hash.new(0)` creates a new hash with a default value of `0`. This value is returned when accessing keys that do not exist in the hash
- `counts[subscription[:item_id]] += 1` will increment the value in the hash by one for the key `subscription[:item_id]`

And there you have counts by `item_id`.

Comment: Is there really the need to separate `each` and `with_object`? Can't you equally do this: `subscriptions.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |subscription, memo| memo[subscription[:item_id]] += 1 }`

Comment: As far as I know, you can use equally `each_with_object` or `each.with_object`. It's a matter of taste. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14672305/177665), `each_with_object` will work directly with each value of the array, whereas `each.with_object` construct will first return an enumerator (`each` part) and then call `with_object` on the enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

`subscriptions.group_by { |h| h[:item_id] }.map { |k,v| [k, v.length] }.to_h`